# Delete entire row won't stay capitalized

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete entire rows with duplicate values. If the values in column "E" are the same in two rows, I want to delete all row with that value that is duplicated.

The other fields might be or not duplicates of that row and there might be up to ten duplicates and the total number of rows is large *( #rows >4000)*. This is just one part of a large macro, so I cannot use excel functions. This is what I have so far for deleting rows:

```
    Sub AAAAH()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Dim i As Single
    Dim j As Single


    BottomLineRelease = Sheets("Hours Of Interest").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    rowcount = Sheets("Hours Of Interest").Range("E2:E" & BottomLineRelease).Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To Sheets("Hours Of Interest").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Hours Of Interest").Range("E" & i) = Sheets("Hours Of     Interest").Range("E" & i - 1) Then
            j = i - 1
            Rows(j).Select
            Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
         End If
      Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This not only crashes Excel, but the "Selection.delete Shift: =xlup" will not allow the "delete" to stay capitalized. Every time I click away, it goes back to lower case.

Does anyone know a faster or at least functional way to delete these duplicate rows in VBA?

Comment: um... iterate backwards

Answer (score 2):

`Selection` (=`Application.Selection`) is declared only as `Object` because it can take various objects (a range, a shape object, a chart etc. etc.). Therefore the intellisense doesn't work as well, it is only determined during execution if `.Delete` is a valid method.

Try

```
Sheets("Hours Of Interest").Rows(j).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

If you use Sheets(...).Range in your code, you should never get lazy and never use `Range` or `Rows` or `Cells` without that explicit reference, you *might* be deleting on a different worksheet.

Furthermore, if you delete rows from the top down, every delete changes the row numbers of the following lines.
So you should delete backwars with

```
for i = [..maximum..] to 0 step -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop to isolate unique values.  You can filter column E for unique values, copy those to a new sheet, and delete the old sheet.

```
lastRow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:H" & lastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("E1:E" & lastRow), Unique:=True

Cells.Copy
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("oldSheet").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This is way faster than a loop, if memory serves.